# How do I capture persisted configuration variables upon enabling a Alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When users enable my skill, I want them to enter a few configuration variables that I want to recall throughout the life of the app (while the skill is installed). Is there a tutorial on how to do this?

Workflow:

1. User enables skill through mobile app or the web
2. During that process, the app asks three questions, via a form, to be stored as secure variables
3. When the user uses the skill, those variables are used to execute the action

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This can be with a simple and easy way  : record the entries in a database with the userID as  key.
[you can refere to this tutorial to identify the user and save it to database](https://hackernoon.com/identifying-users-in-alexa-skills-ff189d03ed1d)

Comment: Thanks! How can obtain the entries from the user during the install process?

Comment: ah , i misunderstand your question. in fact, it's not possible that you can have entries while enabling the app from the store but you can ask alexa to ask the user to get this informations